# What does require_auth (_self) do in EOS?

Tags: smart-contract

I have seen in numerous places that the following is coded -

```
require_auth (_self);
```

Aside from the intuitive meaning that it requires a user to be authorised, what exactly does it do and how?

Answer (score 7):

Contracts inherit from `eosio::contract`, and, if we look in [eosiolib/contract.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/contract.hpp) for the base class, we see that the constructor for `eosio::contract` is as follows:

```
contract( account_name n ):_self(n){}
```

Therefore, the account that creates the contract and calls the constructor becomes `_self`. Thus, `require_auth(_self)` ensures that the account executing the function has the authority of the account that created the contract.